# Cascading Combobox returning blank values

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I've attempted to set up cascading comboboxes in Access 2016. However my dependent combobox is showing blank values. the number of rows it returns is correct, however they are all blank.

Any help on how to solve this issue be appreciated, screenshots and code provided below.

Screenshot

[image: Error Example]
As per screenshot, the Channel Source 'Referral' has 2 Lead Sources, I get 2 options, but they both are blank...

Table

```
ID  Channel Source  Lead Source
1   Online  Blog
13  Online  Premium Content
14  Online  Organic Search
15  Marketing   Digital Advertising
16  Marketing   Email Advertising
17  Online  Social Media
18  Marketing   Media Coverage
19  Online  Website
20  Marketing   Direct Marketing
21  Marketing   Traditional Advertising
22  Marketing   Sponsorships
23  Affiliate / Partner Programs    Alinta JV
24  Events / Shows  Renewable Energy Conference 2019
25  Direct  Inbound Phone Calls
26  Direct  Outbound Sales
27  Referral    Retail Account Manager
28  Referral    Existing Customer
29  Existing    Existing Customer
30  Direct  Networking
```

Query Channel Source

```
SELECT DISTINCT Tbl_Channel_Source.[Channel Source] 
FROM Tbl_Channel_Source 
ORDER BY Tbl_Channel_Source.[Channel Source];
```

Query Lead source

```
SELECT Tbl_Channel_Source.[Lead Source] 
FROM Tbl_Channel_Source 
ORDER BY Tbl_Channel_Source.[Lead Source];
```

Code in After_change Channel Source

```
Private Sub Channel_Source_AfterUpdate()
Dim Str As String

Str = " SELECT [Lead Source] " & _
      " FROM Tbl_Channel_Source " & _
      " WHERE [Channel Source]= '" & Me.[Channel_Source] & "'" & _
      " ORDER BY [Lead Source] "

    Me.[Lead_Source].RowSource = Str
    Me.[Lead_Source].Requery

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

the combobox was returning 2 columns, the reason for the blanks was the column width, which was set to 0. I changed this to 2.5 and the values appeared